# is this algorithm O(n^2)?

Tags: java, for-loop, big-o

I have been set a challenge and have been told to solve it in O(n^3) because apparently it is impossible in O(n^2), O(n^2) was the original task but it was changed. The challenge is to write an algorithm that goes through each row of an n*n matrix and then print the whole matrix as a sorted array. Each row of the matrix is already sorted.

Here's what I have and I think it is O(n^2) but am still learning big-O properly so wanted some confirmation if I've done it. It uses an insertion sort utility method to sort the array. Thanks

```
public int[] mergeMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
    int length = matrix.length;
    int [] sortedMatrixArray = new int[length * length];
    int loop = 1;
    for (int[] i : matrix) {
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            switch (loop) {
                case 1:
                    sortedMatrixArray[j] = i[j];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    sortedMatrixArray[j + 3] = i[j];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    sortedMatrixArray[j + 6] = i[j];
                    break;
            }
        }
        loop++;
    }
    insertionSort(sortedMatrixArray);
    return sortedMatrixArray;
}

private void insertionSort(int[] array) {
    for (int firstUnsortedIndex = 0; firstUnsortedIndex < array.length; firstUnsortedIndex++) {
        int newElement = array[firstUnsortedIndex];
        int i;
        for (i = firstUnsortedIndex; i > 0 && array[i-1] > newElement; i--) {
            array[i] = array[i-1];
        }
        array[i] = newElement;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
public int[] mergeMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
    int length = matrix.length;
    int [] sortedMatrixArray = new int[length * length];
    int loop = 0;
    for (int[] i : matrix) {
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if (loop == 0) {
                sortedMatrixArray[j] = i[j];
            }
            sortedMatrixArray[j + (length*loop)] = i[j];
        }
        loop++;
    }
    insertionSort(sortedMatrixArray);
    return sortedMatrixArray;
}
```

Comment: If you're asking whether or not your code is O(n^2), then yes, it is. But are you sure that gives the correct result? The `switch` block and the `loop` variable seem to suggest that it only works for special cases, although I could be mistaken.

Comment: Hi. I have tested it on multiple 2D arrays of different sizes and it gives out a sorted array every time. What special cases are you referring to?

Comment: It's just that I don't understand the point of j+3 and j+6, and there's no case for loop > 3, so then it just does nothing (just spins unnecessarily) after processing the first three rows in the first nested loops... But I'm tired and perhaps not reading the code right. If you have tested it with a large number of randomly generated input matrices and verified the results, then it's probably correct. But are you sure that your test code is correct, then? :-D

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out I have mistakenly been inputting the same array in my tests and thinking it was correct when it wasn't. I have re-written it and re-posted it below the original code. Thanks!!

Comment: That makes much more sense! You could even leave out the `if` statement for the special case of `loop == 0` because j + (length*0) = j. And now I also understand what you are doing: You're creating a one-dimensional array with all the elements from the matrix, and then using a standard sorting algorithm to sort that array.

Comment: This unfortunately also reveals that your algorithm is O(n^4) instead of O(n^2), as pointed out in the answer from talex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `n` is size of matrix, then matrix have `n^2` elements.

Your`insertionSort` take `n^2` element as input. It works `O(k^2)` (where `k` is sze of input), so totally you have `O(n^2^2)` which is `O(n^4)`.

To make it `O(n^3)` you can do following

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] result = sort(new int[][]{{1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {3, 6, 9}});

        System.out.println("result = " + Arrays.toString(result));
    }

    static int[] sort(int[][] matrix) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            total += matrix[i].length;
        }

        // indexes variable store current position for each row.
        int[] indexes = new int[matrix.length];
        int[] result = new int[total];
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            int minIndex = 0;
            int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            // this loop search for row with minimal current position.
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
                //Ignore row which are exhausted
                if (indexes[j] >= matrix[j].length) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (matrix[j][indexes[j]] <= minValue) {
                    minIndex = j;
                    minValue = matrix[j][indexes[j]];
                }
            }
            result[i] = matrix[minIndex][indexes[minIndex]];
            indexes[minIndex]++;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

This algorithm can be improved from `O(n^3)` to `O(n^2*log(n))` using some advanced data structure which allow to find row with minimal current element faster (some sort of tree).

Comment: that's great thanks! I don't want to doubt you but 2 other people here say that my algorithm is O(n^2), how do I know which one of you is right? I thought that for big-O you just use the worst case scenario, so turning the matrix into an array takes O(n^2) and the insertion sort takes O(n^2), doesn't this mean that the worst case is O(n^2) overall? thanks

Comment: When you say "insertion sort takes `O(n^2)`" you should take into account that this is different `n` this new `n` is size of `sortedMatrixArray` which is `n^2` in terms of original `n`. Unfortunately truth in programming not determined by voting :)

Comment: @PumpkinBreath This answer is correct. I was overlooking the fact that the input to the second part of your solution was processing an array that has k = n^2 elements, and the second part has nested loops which makes it O(k^2) = O(n^4). Sorry! :-/

Answer (score -1):

You're right, it is O(n^2). Your insertionSort is also O(n^2) but since you're calling it after your first 2 for loops are completed, your run time is 
O(n^2)+O(n^2)=O(n^2)

Comment: `n` is size of matrix. Matrix have `n^2` elements. Insertion sort work on whole matrix, so it have `O(n^2^2)` complexity.

Comment: the insertion sort only iterates over the sortedMatrixArray, not the matrix

Comment: `sortedMatrixArray` have `n^2` size.